# How to enable split tunneling with L2TP over IPsec VPN on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager, vpn, l2tp

My users are able to connect to L2TP VPN without issues but are having problems with the speeds. To resolve this, I'd like to provide them instructions on how to enable split tunneling so they only have to access the VPN Tunnel for on-site resources.

If it helps, this guide shows how the L2TP VPN is set up on my Ubuntu 18.04 users' machines: https://help.vpntunnel.com/support/solutions/articles/5000782608-vpntunnel-l2tp-installation-guide-for-ubuntu-18-04-

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.

Open a terminal with CTRL-ALT-t

To locate **your-vpn-name**.nmconnection file:

**ls -la /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections**

To edit the file:

**sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/your-vpn-name.nmconnection**

Add to the **[ipv4]** section:

**never-default=true**

AND a route to YOUR remote subnet, for example:

**route1=192.168.0.0/24,192.168.0.254,2**

(i.e. YOUR remote subnet/mask, remote router IP, metric=2. Note that remote subnet/mask cannot be the same as your LAN!)

To save changes and exit nano editor program:

**CTRL-o,Enter,CTRL-x**

To restart NetworkManager:

**sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager**

VPN when switched on then leaves default gateway unchanged.

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, but I understand NetworkManager is the default on Ubuntu 18.04

Good Luck