# l2tp vpn in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, l2tp

I installed ubuntu 22.04 and configed l2tp vpn, after l2tp connected my internet connection broken, why???
I have tried xl2tpd versions (1.3.16-1ubuntu0.1 amd64) and (1.3.12-1.1) but none of them work for me.
after many search I can not find solution.
can anyone help me?

Comment: Is using OpenVPN an option? It usually works flawlessly with an .opvn file.

Answer (score 0):

lt2tp vpn defaults to tunneling all your internet traffic through the VPN.

Here's a link to an answer I posted which stops this from happening, leaving your default gateway unchanged.

[How to enable split tunneling with L2TP over IPsec VPN on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1401053/how-to-enable-split-tunneling-with-l2tp-over-ipsec-vpn-on-ubuntu-18-04/1427707#1427707)

Understand that by preserving your default gateway, you have to supply a route through the VPN to the other LAN.

Hope this helps

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1247959)